# react-native run-android is taking too much time on installaion on my android device

Tags: react-native

I tried to run react-native run-android on my real android device but it was taking too much time and made my system hanged and then crashed the program. Please anyone can suggest what can i do?? I am using windows 10.

Comment: I think its depend on environment of machine,but you should try to use expo for react native project.

Answer (score 0):

You can use expo, it better and faster

Comment: yup but i have read with expo i can use limited libraries only . It may happen if i require any library for my project that will not be available on Expo

Comment: Expo also allows many libraries and even easier and faster to build both ios and android together